# Get nested value from Angular firestore Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with angular 7 using angularFirestore to fetch data from my database. In my database, every user has an account balance of $0. I want to fetch the current user account details which I have done and update that field with after the sum of the previous account which is $0 and the new payment.
The big problem is getting the next field on [amount : $0] from the already fetched data from observable.

i have tried to log the nexted value which is underfine.

on userService.ts

```
this.getUserAccount = database.collection('accounts', ref =>
              ref.where('email', '==', getUser) ).valueChanges();
```

on my payment.component.ts

```
this.myAccountDetails = userService.getUserAccount;
this.myAccountDetails.subscribe(x => this.databaseAcount = x.data());
setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.databaseAcount );
    }, 3000);
```

gave this result on the console:

```sh
amount: 0
created: Timestamp {seconds: 1561458855, nanoseconds: 534000000}
email: "simboy34@gmail.com"_
_proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

how do I access the amount value?
note: I have tried `console.log(this.databaseAmount.amount)` gives // undefined

Comment: isn't this.databaseAcount in json format ? and have you tried putting console.log in subscribe itself?

Comment: where do you console.log this.databaseAmount.amount? if you console.log inside subscribe, you should be able to see it.

Comment: `console.log(databaseAmount)` inside subscription gave the same values.

Comment: i tried console.log(this.databaseAmount.amount here which gave me null `this.myAccountDetails = userService.getUserAccount;
this.myAccountDetails.subscribe(x => this.databaseAcount = x.data());
setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.databaseAcount.amount );
    }, 3000);`

Comment: Solved . i accessed the amount value with following code                                    ``
  this.db.collection('accounts', reff => {
    return reff.where('email', '==', this.currentUserEmail);
  }).snapshotChanges().subscribe((res: any) => {
res.map(element => this.databaseAcount = element.payload.doc.data().amount); ``